# Remove parent or "wrapping" array

Tags: php, arrays

Alright, I've done some extensive searching for this and I cannot get it to work properly...so I've come looking for some help. What I have is an array I'm creating from a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ( $things as $thing ) :
    $the_array[] = array(
        'field1' => 'value1',
        'field2' => 'value2',
        'field3' => $thing
    );
endforeach;
```

Which gives me this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
       (
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3a
       )

    [1] => Array
       (
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3b
       )

)
```

How do I go about getting this result:

```
[0] => Array
   (
        [field1] => value1
        [field2] => value2
        [field3] => value3a
   )

[1] => Array
   (
        [field1] => value1
        [field2] => value2
        [field3] => value3b
   )
```

I will be inserting these arrays into another array as a child. I have that part working, just the results I expect aren't there due to the wrapping array.

I've tried to manually put `$the_array[0]`, `$the_array[1]`, `$the_array[2]`, `$the_array[3]`, etc. inside the other array and it works, but I don't want to go this route. Is there a way to print out those variables individually based on the count of the initial `$things` array?

And as you can see, I just gave two results as an example. They will vary.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: *Is there a way to print out those variables individually based on the count of the initial `$things` array?* -- do you mean like with a regular `for` loop (`for $i=0; $i<count($things); $i++) print_r($the_array[$i]);`)?

Comment: @rickdenhaan Yea, I forgot to mention I've done that and I got the desired result. How do I go about getting those into the other array?

Comment: Depends on what the other array looks like and where you want to put them. What is the desired end-result?

Comment: It would be inserted into the other array like this: `array( 'existing_field' => 'existing_value', $the_array );`

Comment: So you want to end up with `array('existing_field' => 'existing_value', 0 => array(0 => array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2', 'field3' => 'value3a'), 1 => array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2', 'field3' => 'value3b')))`?

Comment: Close. Without the parent `0`. Like this: `array( 'existing_field' => 'existing_value', 0 => array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2', 'field3' => 'value3a'), 1 => array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2', 'field3' => 'value3b'))`. I've tried to just target `$the_array[0]`, but that just gives me the first result.

Comment: Gotcha. So do you already have an `$other_array` that is just `array('existing_field' => 'existing_value')`? In that case, you can loop through `$the_array` with that basic `for` loop and just do `$other_array[] = $the_array[$i];`

Comment: Come to think of it, a for loop isn't even necessary. Just `$other_array += $the_array` should do it: https://3v4l.org/fqSdI

Comment: Well, damn. That worked. Thank you very, very much for your help, @rickdenhaan. If you want you can add that as the answer and I can mark it as such.

Comment: Glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your end result is this:

```
array(
    'existing_field' => 'existing_value',
    $the_array[0],
    $the_array[1],
    ...$the_array[n]
);
```

You can use either a `for` loop or just add the two arrays:

```
$other_array = array('existing_field' => 'existing_value');

// either this:
for ($i=0; $i<count($things); $i++) {
    $other_array[] = $the_array[$i];
}

// or this:
$other_array += $the_array;
```

That will give you the end result you're looking for:

```
Array
(
    [existing_field] => existing_value
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3b
        )

)
```